# Multiple servers using same nameservers

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, centos

I have 2x servers with the following OS's and Control Panels:

Windows Server 2003 running Plesk 9
Centos 5.3 running WHM/cPanel

The Windows server 2003 server is hosting the two nameservers:

ns1.domain.com
ns2.domain.com

I have BIND running on the Centos 5.3 server, but I wish for my customers to use the same nameservers ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com (as per the Windows Server 2003 server).

My first question is - is this possible? And if so, how would I go about configuring both servers to enable such a configuration?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Tell the CentOS machine to be a slave, and transfer zones from the Windows server, then tell the Windows server to notify the CentOS server on changes, and allow zone transfers from the CentOS box.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply set your CentOS server to use the Windows dns server instead of the local one? Edit your network configuration (either through system-config-network or directly edit /etc/resolv.conf) and set the nameservers as the windows one.

Regardless of that, creating a backup server (on a different machine) is always a good idea so you might want to use womble's answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com virtual machines running on the Windows box? If so, you'll have no DNS servers when the Windows machine goes down unless you do as suggested by Womble. Your customers may get annoyed if your site is unreachable due to a failure in DNS resolution.

You should have at least two DNS servers but they really need to be on separate machines. Ideally they will also be on separate Internet connections. Having them all on one machine defeats the idea of redundancy somewhat.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer. Nope the two nameservers are not virtual machines; ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com both reside on the Windows Server under the one windows installation.

I do however have a third server that I could use for a master DNS server, however how can I "sync" all of the zones?

Comment: Set one up as the master and the others as slaves. Changes on the master will automatically propagate to the slaves, as long as each end has the correct settings and you remember to increment the serial number for the relevant zone each time you make a change.

Comment: Can this be done between cPanel and Plesk servers though?

Comment: I've never used either, so can't say. I would imagine if you can manage DNS at all with those the master/slave setup options should be there also.